# configure VPN programatically using Protocol- L2TP/IPsec android open source code.

Tags: android, vpn, ipsec, l2tp

We are looking for configure VPN programatically using Protocol- L2TP/IPsec  android open source code.

I have tried the https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn/src/com/example/android/toyvpn/ToyVpnClient.java

Here it's configuring the user profile info

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ToyVpnService.class)
.putExtra(prefix + ".ADDRESS", mServerAddress.getText().toString())
.putExtra(prefix + ".PORT", mServerPort.getText().toString())
.putExtra(prefix + ".SECRET", mSharedSecret.getText().toString());
startService(intent);
```

I want to manage the NAME, TYPE, SERVER ADDRESS, IPSEC Pre-shared Key for server VPN setup after that connection with shared USERID and Password.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the way to use configurations with `ToyVpn`. My solution is [strongSwan](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/DeveloperDocumentation) open source vpn client

Comment: Thank you very much, let me try strongSwan from Google Play store APK. Is this working with my specification configuration or not

Comment: I have tried with installing this apk - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.strongswan.android but that's not working for me. When direct i am doing the configuration settings on Mobile settings then working fine but not working with StrongSwan input with my own profile.

Comment: I am compiling the source code using NDK, I will update you soon.

Comment: No, strongSwan does not implement L2TP. I have cross checked the things any another open source code for strongSwan

Comment: I have below info Server-X.X.X.X Protocol- L2TP/IPsec PSK- 123456 PORT- L2TP -udp 1701 After connecting, this are the dialer credentials- username- XXXX password- XXXX please let me know how can i connect this via android code

Comment: You can look at {https://github.com/vmlinz/strongswan-android} project. Connection starts from profile and vpn type creation. See `VpnProfile.java` and `VpnType.java`

Comment: @user909026 I hope u do well, and I want to know did u made to create a Lt2p VPN in android programmatically if yes please answer since I need so urgent.

Comment: @kh_4 Did you find any code for L2TP, were you able to implement it?

Comment: @Micer did you find a solution?

Comment: @user7856586 No sorry, I tried to use Strongswan, but it's quite complex.

Comment: @Micer thx we made it by using c libs from [open vpn](https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn)

Comment: @StanislavBondar this library is working fine for you?